# How to Sign a UWP app on Azure Pipelines?

Tags: uwp, certificate, azure-pipelines-build-task

The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps) about setting up Azure Pipelines for a UWP doesn't say how to sign the package. It does say that the cert file should be in the repo but it doesn't explain how to sign the package with that cert.

So my question is how do I sign a UWP package on Azure Pipelines?
Am I supposed to create a powershell script to run `SignTool`?

Comment: Depends what you want to do with the app. I currently use signtool to sign with our in house cert. You can also use the WACK to verify the app and then install the cert that's produced during deploy

Comment: @McNline I just came across this post. You're able to use a certificate on one of your on-premises servers, in an Azure Pipeline, to sign an app? If so, I'd like to learn more, please.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, following these tasks would do the trick.

1. Create the certificate
2. Download the certificate
3. Install the certificate
4. Build
5. Copy
6. Public Artifacts
7. Distribute to App Center if you have any (Optional)

Here is the full content of the YAML file, I have this tested and running in my pipeline.

```
# Universal Windows Platform

# Build a Universal Windows Platform project using Visual Studio.
# Add steps that test and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

# A pipeline with no CI trigger
trigger: none
pr: none
name: $(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(date:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(rev:.r)
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
- group: uwp-pipeline
- name: solution
  value: '**/*.sln'
- name: buildPlatform
  value: 'x86|x64'
- name: buildConfiguration
  value: 'Release'
- name: appxPackageDir
  value: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\'
- name: MajorVersion
  value: 1
- name: MinorVersion
  value: 0
- name: customBuildNumber
  value: '$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(date:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(rev:.r)'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: mySecureFile
  displayName: 'Download CA certificate'
  inputs:
    secureFile: '$(signingCert.secureFilePath)'

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "Start adding the PFX file to the certificate store."

      $pfxpath = '$(mySecureFile.secureFilePath)'
      $password = '$(signingCert.password)'      

      Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
      $cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
      $cert.Import($pfxpath, $password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"PersistKeySet")
      $store = new-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -argumentlist "MY", CurrentUser
      $store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadWrite")
      $store.Add($cert)
      $store.Close()

- task: VersionAPPX@2
  inputs:
    Path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    VersionNumber: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    InjectVersion: False
    VersionRegex: '(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])(\.(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])){3}'
    OutputVersion: 'OutputedVersion'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    platform: 'x86'
    solution: '$(solution)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(buildPlatform)" 
                  /p:AppxPackageDir="$(appxPackageDir)" 
                  /p:AppxBundle=Always 
                  /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload 
                  /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true
                  /p:PackageCertificateThumbprint="$(signingCert.thumbprint)" 
                  /p:PackageCertificateKeyFile="$(mySecureFile.secureFilePath)"
                  /p:PackageCertificatePassword="$(signingCert.password)"'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
    Contents: '**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'release to app center'
    appSlug: '$(appSlug)'
    buildVersion: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    appFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    releaseNotesOption: 'input'
    releaseNotesInput: 'New release!'
    destinationType: 'groups'
    distributionGroupId: '$(distributionGroupId)'
```

I had written a detailed article on the same, please feel free to read it here: [UWP Application Signin, Release, Distribute, Deploy With Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://medium.com/@sibeeshvenu/uwp-application-singin-release-distribute-deploy-with-azure-devops-pipeline-118580bd4d75)

Comment: can you not create certificate using VS 2019? why do you need to generate using powershell? is it any different?

Comment: Hi Sibeesh Venu. I use you pipeline but i got an error on PoweShell task. Error is : "Exception calling "Import" with "3" argument(s): "X509Certificate is immutable on this platform. Use the equivalent constructor instead." . some idea?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do with the app. I currently use signtool to sign with our in house cert.

```
signtool sign /a /d "{certName}" /fd sha256 /n "{publisherName}" /td sha256 /tr "http://timestamp.comodoca.com" /v "$(TargetPath)"
```

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/using-signtool-to-sign-a-file

You can also use the WACK to verify the app and then install the cert that's produced during deploy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-app-certification-kit

Comment: so you're saying that I shoulduse SignTool in powershell script. I don't understand why the doc about azure pipeline doesn't explicitly say so. Or even why there isn't a task rather than a ps1 script.

Comment: There are different ways to do it. When you publish the UWP project a cert is automatically created.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps

I usually just sign it locally before deploying. But yes, if you create a PS script to run on the pipeline you should be fine

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=tfs-2018-2