# Code signing (Self-signed cert) for WPF app with Secure File library in Azure CI Pipeline

Tags: wpf, azure-pipelines, clickonce, code-signing, self-signed-certificate

I have a WPF application, and I had created the CI pipeline to build the application and publish the ClickOnce package. Everything works fine when Sign Manifest is turn off. However, when Sign Manifest is set to true, I hit the error:

`Error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.`

I had been reading a lot from google, finally I choose Secure File Library (over Azure Key Vault).
What I had done so far:

1. Upload the PFX file to Secure File Library
2. Create the Variable Group for the password
3. Link the CI pipeline to the Variable Group
4. Add a task in CI pipeline to download the secure file:

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: mySecureFile
  inputs:
    secureFile: $(secureFilePath)
```

5. Add another powershell task to add the pfx above to the certification store:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "Start adding the PFX file to the certificate store."

      $pfxpath = '$(mySecureFile.secureFilePath)'
      $password = '$(securePassword)'

      Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
      $cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
      $cert.Import($pfxpath, $password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"PersistKeySet")
      $store = new-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -argumentlist "MY", CurrentUser
      $store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadWrite")
      $store.Add($cert)
      $store.Close()
```

6. Then finally the build and publish

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: 
      '
        /target:restore,publish
        /p:Configuration=$(buildConfiguration)
        /p:Platform=$(buildPlatform)
        /p:MyAssemblyName=$(assemblyName)
        /p:InstallUrl=$(installUrl)
        /p:PublishUrl=$(installUrl)
        /p:ApplicationVersion=$(publishVersion)
        /p:ProductName=$(productName)
        /p:PublisherName=$(publisherName)
        /p:MyGenerateManifests=true
        /p:PackageCertificateThumbprint="$(thumbprint)" 
        /p:PackageCertificateKeyFile="$(mySecureFile.secureFilePath)"
        /p:PackageCertificatePassword="$(securePassword)"
        /p:NoWarn=0618
        /p:OutputPath="$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\\"
      '
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\app.publish'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58763552

So after all this is set, I run the pipeline with this error:

`##[error]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(6053,5): Error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.`

Note:

the pfx cert I got was believe to be self-signed as I cannot see any CA. The cert validity is 2016-2040. Can I (or should I) use a self-signed cert in the CI pipeline to sign my click once package (deployment manifest and assembly?